# Can't bake anymore

Tags: texture-baking, baking

I know this has already been asked before, I checked almost every question I found from Stack-exchange to CGcookie and blenderartists  and other forums , I followed every instruction step by step ... yet none of the answers worked. 
[image]

It's been an hour I'm trying to bake this thing and I have no idea what's wrong... it used to work, I already did it before but it seems blender has started to hate me...

I'm about to throw my computer out of the window...

Do I have to re-instal blender?

Comment: What option did you change before being able to bake?

Comment: only the numpad emulator... I tried to reset it  with load factory settings and it didn't work .....

Comment: It looks like you use Blender Internal. It *could* be a bug (somewhat long ago it occured once to me and didn't ever become clear what was wrong) but to check that please [upload the file](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/) or a part of the problem mesh (delete anything else) and comment with a link / edit a question. Also what bake are you trying to do ?

Comment: I'm trying to bake a multi-resolution  model   to a low poly one, though can't uppload a file , it is too heavy even though I have amputated parts of the model but it excess the limit by 40 MiB

Comment: The error can happen when Blender looses association with the texture set. In my case I detached the image texture in the compositor and then then reloaded and re-connected the node. In theory I changed nothing, but the refresh worked for me. Hope it does for you...

Comment: I don't know, it seems to work with any other model but this.... at this point I'm just sculpting it again...

Comment: Did you try importing it into another project / file and baking from there ?

Comment: yes, I tried it....

Comment: blender is not damaged and you do not damage your mesh is not damaged, what was damaged was your .blend is damaged, and it is very difficult to recover a damaged blend has already happened to me on other occasions with very large files, those little things that are undesirable blenders, such as their instability and crash when you are about to finish a model jajajjaajjajaja